# Duplicated has_many records using accepts_nested_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid4

Using Rails 4 and Mongoid 4 from master

For some odd reason I am getting duplicated child records when a record fails validation (but not when it is valid) the form that then renders back to the user has the extra records in it

I have a Pipeline, which has many PipelineStages

Editing a Stage name to blank (which will fail validation) duplicates all the Pipeline.pipeline_stages

```
class Pipeline
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :pipeline_stages, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pipeline_stages, allow_destroy: true
end

class PipelineStage
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :pipeline
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum:50 }
end
```

So when passed into the controller, what appear to be perfectly valid params don't work when update_attributes is used

```
[1] pry(#<PipelinesController>)> valid_params
=> {"name"=>"ddd",
 "pipeline_stages_attributes"=>
  {"0"=>
    {"id"=>"534f170e4a616b8368960000",
     "name"=>"dddd",
     "_destroy"=>"false",
     "sort_order"=>"9999"},
   "1"=>
    {"id"=>"534f1b554a616b8368a70000",
     "name"=>"",
     "_destroy"=>"false",
     "sort_order"=>"9999"}}}
[2] pry(#<PipelinesController>)> @pipeline.pipeline_stages
=> [#<PipelineStage _id: 534f170e4a616b8368960000, created_at: 2014-04-16 23:49:34 UTC, updated_at: 2014-04-16 23:49:34 UTC, pipeline_id: BSON::ObjectId('534f170e4a616b8368950000'), name: "dddd", stage_number: nil, sort_order: 9999>, 
 #<PipelineStage _id: 534f1b554a616b8368a70000, created_at: 2014-04-17 00:07:49 UTC, updated_at: 2014-04-17 00:07:57 UTC, pipeline_id: BSON::ObjectId('534f170e4a616b8368950000'), name: "asdasdsadasd2", stage_number: nil, sort_order: 9999>]

[3] pry(#<PipelinesController>)> @pipeline.update_attributes(valid_params)
=> false

[4] pry(#<PipelinesController>)> @pipeline.pipeline_stages
=> [#<PipelineStage _id: 534f170e4a616b8368960000, created_at: 2014-04-16 23:49:34 UTC, updated_at: 2014-04-16 23:49:34 UTC, pipeline_id: BSON::ObjectId('534f170e4a616b8368950000'), name: "dddd", stage_number: nil, sort_order: 9999>, 
 #<PipelineStage _id: 534f1b554a616b8368a70000, created_at: 2014-04-17 00:07:49 UTC, updated_at: 2014-04-17 00:07:57 UTC, pipeline_id: BSON::ObjectId('534f170e4a616b8368950000'), name: "asdasdsadasd2", stage_number: nil, sort_order: 9999>, 
 #<PipelineStage _id: 534f170e4a616b8368960000, created_at: 2014-04-16 23:49:34 UTC, updated_at: 2014-04-16 23:49:34 UTC, pipeline_id: BSON::ObjectId('534f170e4a616b8368950000'), name: "dddd", stage_number: nil, sort_order: 9999>, 
 #<PipelineStage _id: 534f1b554a616b8368a70000, created_at: 2014-04-17 00:07:49 UTC, updated_at: 2014-04-17 00:07:57 UTC, pipeline_id: BSON::ObjectId('534f170e4a616b8368950000'), name: "", stage_number: nil, sort_order: 9999>]
```